# Merge vertical lists in Vim

Tags: list, vim

Is there a way which allows me to merge lists vertically?

For example, if I have have these two lists:

```
A E
B F
C G
D H
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```
A
E
B
F
C
G
D
H
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is simple, just place the cursor on the column between the lists.
Insert visualblock-mode `<C-v>`, mark the whole column, hit `r` to replace it, and then `<CR>` and you have what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/\v^(\w) /\1\r/g

: ........... command
% ........... whole file
\v .......... very magic (avoid backslashes)
(\w) ........ word character
\1 .......... all patter in parenthesis 
\r .......... Carriage Return "Enter"
g ........... globally
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with an external filter. Mark the relevant lines in visual mode and press <kbd>!</kbd>. The following filter does what you want on a POSIX system:

```
paste -sd' ' | tr ' ' '\n'
```